# install_failed_older_sdk error Delphi 10.1 Berlin

Tags: android, delphi, sdk, delphi-10.1-berlin

i'm using Delphi 10.1 Berlin for Android programming. When clicking compile the project get older sdk error. I can not change AndoridManifest.xml because the file loading dynamicly and recreating when run project. Delphi XE7 no problem but Delphi 10.1 Berlin (SDK 24) getting the error.

My Phone: LG P920
Android Version: 2.3.5
SDK Tools: installed (2.3.3-2.3.7 API 10 and other new versions)
Delphi: 10.1 Berlin
Windows 7

[General](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1xSe.jpg)

[SDK properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgBNT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you won't get very far with Delphi 10.1 Berlin and your device. According to [Embarcadero's Delphi 10.1 Seattle Android Software Requirements documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development#Android_Software_Requirements), Delphi 10.1 Berlin only supports back to Ice Cream Sandwich, specifically Android 4.0.3 and 4.0.4 (API Level 15).

API Level 10 is no longer supported. It was last supported by Delphi XE7, according to [Embarcadero's Delphi XE7 Seattle Android Software Requirements documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development#Android_Software_Requirements).

General target platform support details for Embarcadero's various Delphi product versions are provided on the [Platform Status](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/PlatformStatus/en/Main_Page) docwiki page.

One other point, though. You are right inasmuch as your Android project's Android\Debug\AndroidManifest.xml file keeps getting re-written each time you build your project. However if you want to change what is written out to it you can quite readily do so by editing the project's AndroidManifest.template.xml file in the project folder.